# Sumar dos columnas SQL server con alias

Tags: sql-server, sql

tengo una consulta en la que utilizo dos case when para traer un valor en dolares y otro en pesos, para calcular el valor de la deuda en dolares consulto en otra base de datos la tasa del día. Necesito sumar esos dos valores para totalizarlos, con lo que tengo siempre me trae el valor de la deuda total como 0.He intentado de varias formas y no he podido lograrlo, esta es la consulta:

```
declare @dolar as int
declare @periodo as char(7)
declare @prueba as int
set @periodo = '2020-12'
set @dolar = (select top 1 usd.monto from bi.nvs_dw.dbo.bc_dolar as usd order by Fecha Desc)


(select  s.COD_PER, s.RUT_CLI, [dbo].[FN_ElEspac](a.NOMBRE_CLI) as Nombre_Cliente, s.CTA_CLI, 
isnull(case when s.CTA_CLI like 'CCTE' and s.SALDO_DISP < 0 then s.SALDO_DISP else 0 end,0) as Pesos,
isnull (case when s.CTA_CLI like 'CDOL' and s.SALDO_DISP < 0 then s.SALDO_DISP * @dolar  end,0) as 'Dolares tasa del día',
isnull(sum(case s.CTA_CLI when 'CCTE'  then s.Saldo_Disp end) + sum(case s.CTA_CLI when 'CDOL' then s.SALDO_DISP * @dolar end),0) as Deuda



from ai.BCS.dbo.TBCTCTCL as s 

inner join  ai.bcs.dbo.tbplficl AS a

on s.RUT_CLI = a.RUT_CLI and s.SEC_RUT_CLI = a.SEC_RUT_CLI

where s.SALDO_DISP<0 and s.COD_PER = @periodo
group by s.COD_PER, s.RUT_CLI, s.sec_rut_cli, a.NOMBRE_CLI, s.SALDO_DISP, s.CTA_CLI) 
order by s.RUT_CLI
```

Me trae el resultado de la suma siempre en 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si por favor me pueden decir que me está faltando

Comment: Creo que la sintaxis del sum esta mal... debería ser `CASE WHEN` no? Tú lo tienes como `CASE s.CTA_CLI WHEN`...

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera `CASE` tiene 2 sintaxis y está usando ambas de forma correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios pasos para generar el problema que estás viendo.

El primero es que tu expresión `CASE` no tiene un `ELSE` y por lo tanto puede retornar valores nulos.

Después, tenemos que estás agrupando por la columna `CTA_CLI`, la cual es parte de la condición de tu `CASE` y siempre regresará falso para una de las dos condiciones, por lo que termina siendo un valor nulo.

Por último, se integra la suma de un valor cualquiera más un valor nulo y tenemos como resultado un valor nulo.

Esto se puede resolver usando ISNULL alrededor de ambas sumatorias o usando `ELSE` en ambas condiciones. Por mi parte, preferiría además usar un CTE para escribir las condicionales una sola vez.

```
DECLARE @dolar AS INT
DECLARE @periodo AS CHAR(7)
DECLARE @prueba AS INT

SET @periodo = '2020-12'
SET @dolar = (
        SELECT TOP 1 usd.monto
        FROM bi.nvs_dw.dbo.bc_dolar AS usd
        ORDER BY Fecha DESC
        );

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  s.COD_PER
            ,s.RUT_CLI
            ,a.NOMBRE_CLI
            ,s.CTA_CLI
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.CTA_CLI = 'CCTE'
                        THEN s.SALDO_DISP
                    ELSE 0 END) AS Pesos
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.CTA_CLI = 'CDOL'
                        THEN s.SALDO_DISP * @dolar
                    ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dolares'
        
    FROM ai.BCS.dbo.TBCTCTCL       AS s
    INNER JOIN ai.bcs.dbo.tbplficl AS a ON s.RUT_CLI     = a.RUT_CLI
                                       AND s.SEC_RUT_CLI = a.SEC_RUT_CLI
    WHERE s.SALDO_DISP < 0
      AND s.COD_PER = @periodo
    GROUP BY s.COD_PER,
             s.RUT_CLI,
             a.NOMBRE_CLI,
             s.sec_rut_cli --Esta columna no está en el select
)
 SELECT  s.COD_PER,
         RUT_CLI,
         [dbo].[FN_ElEspac](NOMBRE_CLI) AS Nombre_Cliente,
         CTA_CLI,
         Pesos,
         Dolares AS 'Dolares tasa del día'
         Dolares + Pesos AS Deuda
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RUT_CLI;
```